# cross-reference multiple values in list that fall within specific deviation Vision OCR c#

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, computer-vision, vision

Whilst using Vision OCR in c# xamarin. I found that the API returns text that is supposed to be in 1 region, in different regions. This causes unexcpected behaviour and incorrect processing of the data.

To solve this, Im required to extract the Y coordinates from the boundingboxes on the lines, save the accompanying data.
Add both to a list.
Cross reference each list entry with all the others. When two Y coordinates fall within a deviation of 10 they need to be combined.

I added a transcript below of the structure of the code. I tried using tuples, dictionaries, structs etc. But couldn't find a solution for cross referencing the values for any of them.

Does anyone have a pointer in the right direction?

UPDATE; Im making good progress using a recursive binary search combined with a tuple comparer. Il post the code if/when it works.

```
    class Playground
    {
        public void meh()
        {
            //these are the boundingboxes of different regions when the returned value from the OCR api is parsed
            // int[] arr=new int[]{ Left X, Top Y, Width, Height};
            int[] arrA =new int[] { 178, 1141, 393, 91 };//item 3 xenos
            int[] arrB =new int[] { 171, 1296, 216, 53 };//totaal 3items
            int[] arrC =new int[] { 1183, 1134, 105, 51};//item 3 prijs
            int[] arrD =new int[] { 1192, 1287, 107, 52 };//totaal prijs

            //the strings as will be made available within the lines, as words
            string strA = "item 3";
            string strB = "totaal:";
            string strC = "2,99";
            string strD = "8,97";

            //make list to hold our fake linedata
            List<int[]> ourLines = new List<int[]>();
            ourLines.Add(arrA); ourLines.Add(arrB); ourLines.Add(arrC); ourLines.Add(arrD);


            //following structure is observed
            for(int region = 0; region < 3; region++){
                //3 regions for each region process lines
                foreach(int[] lineData in ourLines)
                {
                    //get Y coordinates from boundingbox which is: lineData[1]
                    //keep int in memory and link* words in the corresponding line to it.
                    //put int and its words in array outside region loop.
                    //repeat this a couple of 100 times

                    for (int words = 0; words < 180; words++)
                    {
                        //do stuff with words
                    }
                }
            }

            //here i need a list with the Y coordinates (for example 1141, 1296,1134, 1287)
            //cross reference all Y coordinates with eachother
            //when they fall withing a deviation of 10 with another
            //then build string with combined text
            //search in text for words resembing 'total' and check if there is an approperiate monetary value.

            //the above would link the values of arrays A + C and B + D. 
            //which causes the corresponding results to be; 'item 3 2.99' and 'totaal 8.97'
            //currently the arrays A+B are returned in region one and C+D in region two. This also varies from image to image.



            //necessary because vision OCR api sometimes decides that lists of productname + price do belong in 2 different regions
            //same for totals, and this causes incorrect responses when reading the data. (like thinking the amount of products == the price
            //so if you bought 3 items the ocr will think the total price is 3$. instead of 8.97 (when each item is 2.99)

            //note, values are monetary and culture independant. so this can mean the values can be in xx.xx or xx,xx
            //* with link i mean either make a tuple/list/struct/keyvaluepair/dictionary/or preferably something more approperiate.
            // this code will be executed on android and iOS devices.. something lightweight is preferred.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not too understand ,is this an algorithmic issue or related to the OCR  API?

Comment: The way the OCR API returns the data in their regions prevents me from checking the lines with both text and numeric values. To fix that i am working on this algorithm. So id say its an algorithmic issue.